# LSTM Price Prediction Plot - ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I'm studying Machine Learning and am working on a project on which I'm stuck when trying to plot LSTM predictions for stock prices. Some information about what I am doing:

- I used AAPL for analysis
- Univariate time series prediction, took the close_price as my variable
- Predict 1 stock price ahead.
- Divided the data into train, test (0.9 , 0.1)
- After created time series with 50 time steps
- My X_test is always of shape : (890,50,1), ytest.shape(890,)

Using this function to create the time series for LSTM:

```
def new_timeseries(dataset, time_steps):
  data_X, data_Y = [], []

  for i in range(time_steps, len(dataset)):
    data_X.append(dataset[i-time_steps:i, 0])
    data_Y.append(dataset[i, 0])
  return np.array(data_X), np.array(data_Y)
```

The shape I feed into the LSTM model is:

```
X_train: (8410,50,1)
y_train: (8410,)
```

My prediction shapes are:

```
X_test: (890,50,1)
y_test: (890,)
y_pred_lstm: (890,50,1)
```

For linear regression and RNN layers I could make and plot predictions as the shape of y_pred_rnn and y_pred_lr is:

```
(890,1)
```

I get the ValueError

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

when I want to plot the single next prediction for LSTM with this code:

```
def plot_series(x, y, color='r'):
  plt.figure(figsize=(8,6), num=1)
  plt.plot(x.reshape(-1), 'o-')
  plt.scatter(51, y, c=color)
  plt.grid(True)
```

```
# Plot predictions 
plot_series(X_train[0], y_test[0], color='g')
plot_series(X_train[0], y_pred_lstm[0], color='r')
plt.show()
```

I would like to know what I must to be able to plot my predictions? Why does the LSTM model make predictions with shape (890,50,1)? Does LSTM always make predictions with shapes of the timesteps you use? As now my shape of y_test and y_pred_lstm are not equal. And if I need to reshape my y_test, in what shape should I make it?

I would really appreciate some help as to what I should do so I can make predictions with the LSTM model on this stock data.

Anything helps!

Comment: You are trying to plot 50 different time steps, all containing x amount of data per time step.  I believe your code for plotting is build for comparing time steps one at a time, not all at once.  Is your goal to compare individual time steps to each other or collectively as a group?

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for responding, I try to compare them collectively as a group